# Identify if all the values of tools aren't null (Xamarin VS 2015 Android)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the following tools in my android app.

1. EditText
2. Spinner
3. ImageView

I also have a button where if you click it, a dialog box will appear and will tell the user if all the tools above are not null. (EditText has inputted text, Spinner has a value selected, and ImageView has image uploaded)

What I want to accomplish is how should the button be able to determine that all those tools have values.

Here is my code so far:

```
private void DialogBox(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            empName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
            request = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText3);
            phase = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);
            spinner1 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);
            spinner2 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner2);
            _imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

            if ((_imageView != null) && (empName.Text != null) && (request.Text != null) && (phase.Text != null) && (spinner1 != null) && (spinner2 != null))
            {
                Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.Create();
                alertDialog.SetTitle("Successful!");
                alertDialog.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo);
                alertDialog.SetMessage("Your request is successful.");
                alertDialog.SetButton("OK", (s, ev) =>
                {

                });
                alertDialog.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.Create();
                alertDialog.SetTitle("Not successful!");
                alertDialog.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo);
                alertDialog.SetMessage("Please make sure you fill up all the information.");
                alertDialog.SetButton("OK", (s, ev) =>
                {

                });
                alertDialog.Show();
            }

        }
```

The problem here is it always gives me the successful alert even if I haven't inputted anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty text box is not necessarily null.  The best way to check for an "empty" value is to use

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(empName.Text)
```

if you want to check for "not empty" use

```
!String.IsNullOrEmpty(empName.Text)
```

these is also a `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` which also checks for blanks in addition to empty values

Comment: Thanks, this works! What about the spinner and imageview? Is there a correct syntax to check if they're empty?